# regular expression needed to rewrite URLs

Tags: asp.net, regex, url-rewriting

I am trying to make a rewrite rule to check whether the URL ends with `.htm` or `.html`, but does not contain `Archive.aspx`.

The url starts out like

```
www.contoso.com/test.htm  (or .html)
```

and ends up like

```
www.contoso.com/Archive.aspx?page=/test.htm
```

How can I do this with a regular expression?

Answer (score 1):

You can use negative lookahead: `(?!Archive\.aspx).*\.html?$`